# Algebra manipulation for a integral

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

When deriving the integral ${\int_0^3(x^3-6x) dx}$ in terms of reimann sums it has these two steps in my calculus book, Stewart 7th edition, and I don't understand how to derive the 2nd from the first.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{ {81 \over n^4} \left[ {n(n+1) \over 2} \right]^2 - {54 \over n^2 } \cdot { n(n+1) \over 2} \right\}
$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ {81 \over 4} \left( 1 + \frac1n \right)^2 - 27 \left( 1 + \frac1n \right) \right]
$$

More specifically, I don't understand how to go from 
$$
{81 \over n^4} \left[ {n(n+1) \over 2} \right]^2
$$ 
to
$$
{81 \over 4} \left( 1 + \frac1n \right)^2
$$
and similarly with the second term. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{1}{n^4} \left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{n^4} \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} = 
\frac{1}{4}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2} = \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{4} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^2, $$
using that $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ for integer $k$ repeatedly.